# Express a set in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given $B=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1\right\}$, $\alpha \in(0, \pi)$ find the volume of
> $$
> S_{\alpha}=\left\{(x, y, z) \in B: z \geq(\cos \alpha) \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right\}
> $$

How can I express $S_{\alpha}$ in spherical coordiates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta\sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$S_{\alpha}=\left\{(x, y, z) \in B: z \geq(\cos \alpha) \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right\}$

Given $z \geq(\cos \alpha) \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}} \ , \alpha \in (0,\pi)$

$\rho \cos\phi \geq \rho\cos\alpha \implies \phi \leq \alpha$

So to find volume of $S_{\alpha}$, you integrate the same way as you do for the whole sphere i.e. the bounds of $\rho$ and $\theta$ remain the same but instead of $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$, you need to use the bounds $0 \leq \phi \leq \alpha$.